# React: tell state that class instance has mutated

Tags: reactjs, immutability

I have this class:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.value = 'foo';
  }

  mutate() {
    this.value = 'bar';
  }
}
```

And a component that has an instance in its state:

```
let Component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      element: new Myclass()
    };
  },
  mutateElement: function() {
    this.state.element.mutate();
  }
});
```

How can I let `<Component />` know that `this.state.element` has mutated and that it needs to re-render?

Using [React immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) won't work as the following syntax is not valid:

```
mutate() {
  this = update(this, {value: {$set: 'bar'}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this. First is the easy way: `this.forceUpdate()`
But react specifically [tells](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) to avoid it as much as possible. But I feel you have a valid use case.

```
let Component = React.createClass({ 
    getInitialState: function() { 
        return { element: new Myclass() }; 
    }, 
    mutateElement: function(){ 
        this.state.element.mutate();
        this.forceUpdate();
    } 
});
```

But if you want to stick with not using `this.forceUpdate()` you could have another variable in state and set that.

```
let Component = React.createClass({ 
    getInitialState: function() { 
        return { element: new Myclass(),
        hasChanged: false }; 
    }, 
    mutateElement: function(){ 
        this.state.element.mutate();
        this.setState({hasChanged: true});
    } 
});
```

This will mutate it and also re-render your component.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know is to clone an instance. For example _.cloneDeep() from lodash.
But this will affect performance.

Comment: Conceptually, this is different: cloning means creating a new object while mutating modifies the same object. Consequences can vary quite a lot.

Comment: yes, but react's life cycles can't catch mutation of instance when called method of instance

Comment: Which is why, IMHO, JS classes should be able to override their `===` operator, so that on a new component lifecycle comparison, `this.state.element !== this.prevState.element`.